# How to flip values of two rows?

Tags: oracle, sql-update

```
ID  TYPE      ORDER_INDEX  CITY_ID
-----------------------------------
1   CAT            1          1
2   DOG            2          1
3   CAT            4          2 
4   DOG            5          2
5   BEE            9          1
```

For each city I need to swap the `order_index` of `cat` and `dog`.

So city with ID 1 should have cat=2 and dog=1, city with ID 2 would have cat=5 and dog=4.

How can this be done with pure SQL?

Comment: Will there only ever be 1 dog and 1 cat per city?  What if a city has 2 dogs and one cat, or 1 dog and zero cats, or 1 dog, 1 cat, and 1 horse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an update:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET ORDER_INDEX = (SELECT t2.ORDER_INDEX FROM yourTable t2
                   WHERE t2.CITY_ID = t1.CITY_ID AND
                         t2.TYPE IN ('CAT', 'DOG') AND
                         t2.TYPE <> T1.TYPE)
WHERE TYPE IN ('CAT', 'DOG');
```

The above update logic assumes that you wish to do the `ORDER_INDEX` swap between dog/cat pair records having the same `CITY_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't care about `ID`, then there's a simple option which does what you wanted:

Before:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID TYP ORDER_INDEX    CITY_ID
---------- --- ----------- ----------
         1 CAT           1          1
         2 DOG           2          1
         3 CAT           4          2
         4 DOG           5          2
         5 BEE           9          1
```

Update:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    type = decode(type, 'DOG', 'CAT', 'DOG')
  3  where type in ('CAT', 'DOG');

4 rows updated.
```

After; requirement was

> city with ID 1 should have cat=2 and dog=1, city with ID 2 would have cat=5 and dog=4.

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID TYP ORDER_INDEX    CITY_ID
---------- --- ----------- ----------
         1 DOG           1          1  --> city with ID = 1 has DOG = 1 ...
         2 CAT           2          1  --> ... and CAT = 2
         3 DOG           4          2  --> city with ID = 2 has DOG = 4 ...
         4 CAT           5          2  --> ... and CAT = 5
         5 BEE           9          1

SQL>
```